# Cant type in output terminal python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i am trying to run a simple input program but I cant type in the output terminal.Thanks
[image]

Comment: That looks like you might be in a "read-only" view, try going to the "terminal" tab next to the "output" tab

Comment: that vscode-output cli you cant type anything there

Answer (score 5):

Code Runner shows results in **OUTPUT** and doesn't accept inputs by default. Add

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

in Settings.json, then you can input data.

Answer (score 0):

File -Reference - Setting
- code runner : Run in terminal
whether to run code in integrated terminal

This works in mine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).